# Stop watching events in Google Calendar API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Assuming I am watching to events using a channel.

What is the easiest way to stop receiving notifications?

Can the callback just return 404 http status code?

Comment: You can choose to stop receiving notifications for a particular channel before it expires by calling the stop method at the following URI:

https://www.googeapis.google.com/calendar/v3/channels/stop . Here is the link for additional information https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#stopping

Comment: I need to use the token for this.. but from an app perspective, I don't want to login in order to unwatch...

Answer (score 2):

No, an error status code does not stop you from receiving notifications. In fact, error status codes will cause more notifications as explained in the [excerpt](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#responding) below:

> To indicate success, you can return any of the following status codes:
>   200, 201, 202, 204, or 102. If your service returns 500, 502, 503, or
>   504, the Google Calendar API will retry with exponential backoff.

According to their [API reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/channels/stop), you need to do an HTTP POST request like that below to stop the notifications. No tokens necessary.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/channels/stop
Authorization: Bearer {auth_token_for_current_user}
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "id": "4ba78bf0-6a47-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a66",
  "resourceId": "ret08u3rv24htgh289g"
}
```

In a different [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404356/how-to-stop-watch-on-entire-channel-of-google-calendar-events), I have asked about the purpose of the `resourceId` here.

Comment: "No tokens necessary" and `{auth_token_for_current_user}` in example. I want to stop watching without token, is it possible?

Comment: @iofjuupasli, I meant that no channel tokens are necessary. You still need the auth token for authentication/security purposes