# How to stop watch on entire channel of Google calendar events?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

How do I stop watching the entire channel? The [API reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/channels/stop) reproduced below requires a `resourceId`, seemingly implying that it only stops watching the event specific to the `resourceId`. For my purposes, I would think that a `channelId` is enough and therefore uncertain what to put for `resourceId`. The field is not optional.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/channels/stop
Authorization: Bearer {auth_token_for_current_user}
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "id": "4ba78bf0-6a47-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a66",
  "resourceId": "ret08u3rv24htgh289g"
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to give resource id, then only option is to set expiration time for the channel which stops notifications automatically. check this link here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#stopping

Comment: @SCG Are you saying that there is no way to stop notification channels on demand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the `resourceId` has nothing to do with the event that caused the push notification. In your app, you should store both the `channelId` and `resourceId` and provide it as required to stop notifications. Still not sure why Google requires two ids for a single purpose. Seems redundant.

Comment: Could you confirm that the `resourceId` to be used is the one obtained from the response of a post to [watch events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch)? I'm confused since this looks like a resourceId specific to an event.

Comment: @guival Yes, it's the `resourceId` from the response of creating a watch