# Google Push Notifications: stop notifications

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google Calendar API and I have problems with [Google Calendar Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push).

When I make a Watch Request I have to send to Google a `Channel Id` and Google send me the `Resource Id` in the response.

If I want to stop notifications for the channel, I have to send to Google both `Channel Id` and `Resource Id`.

If I lose one of these two values, I can't stop the channel.

Is there a way to stop all the channels or a channel knowing only the `Channel Id`?

**Edit:**

The solution is simple... I can get the Channel Id and the Resource Id from a notification, and then I can stop the channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, when you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/channels/stop), the structure required to supply in the request body is:

```
{
  "id": string,
  "resourceId": string
}
```

I think this is required to stop notifications and supported in Google Calendar API as of the moment.

You can follow this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404356/how-to-stop-watch-on-entire-channel-of-google-calendar-events), which is related to your question.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, the solution is to get them from a notification.